# Does this electronic configuration violate the Hund's rule of maximum multiplicity?

Tags: electronic-configuration

[image: Electronic configuration]
I know this configuration violates the AufBau principal but does it also violate Hund's rule of maximum multiplicity?

Comment: No, I don't think it does. Why do you think it violates the maximum multiplicity rule?

Comment: Because Hund's rule says that all unpaired electrons must have the same spin, but I don't know if unpaired electrons in one orbital can have one spin and unpaired electrons in another orbital can have the opposite spin without breaking the rule

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund's_rule_of_maximum_multiplicity and https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Electronic_Structure_of_Atoms_and_Molecules/Electronic_Configurations/Hund%27s_Rules

Comment: You got the definition slightly wrong, Hund's rule basically states that degenerate (i.e. equal in energy) levels must be filled up before pairing of electrons starts, and  those unpaired electrons must have the same spin.

Comment: So, $\ce{3p_x}$, $\ce{3p_y}$, $\ce{3p_z}$ are degenerate, because they have the same energy. So, these levels will each have one electron, all with same spin before the pairing of electron begins.

Comment: But the same rule does not apply to 3p and 3d electrons because their energies are different. So your diagram does not violate Hund's rule (but it is wrong due to Aufbau principle, as you have noticed)